# Lista de String a Int En Haskell

Tags: lista, string, haskell, int

Tengo esta Lista

```
["1234567890"]
```

Y Necesito convertirla en

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Como hago esta conversion de String a Int en Haskell?

Comment: Supongo que algo habrás probado, al menos la conversión de una string en una lista de caractares (que es haskell son equivalentes). También falta ser más específico: ¿qué pasa con los errores de conversión? ¿qué pasa si la lista de entrada tiene más de una string? Puedo darte una solución, pero sin contexto sería una respuesta que no podrías aplicar a tu problema.